# Will the ADC work with resistive inputs in LPC1796

Tags: adc, arm, cortex-m3, lpc

I'm working with [LPC1796](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1769_68_67_66_65_64_63.pdf) and I have to do data acquisition for my project somebody told me that LPC1796 microcontroller won't work with resistive inputs.

What is a resistive input?

Is there any way to work with the same microcontroller on resistive inputs?

Comment: Did somebody also tell you that capital letters and punctuation are not required on this site? A link to the PROPER data sheet of the chip is probably also going to help you get an answer.

Comment: Huh?  What's a *"resistive input"*?  No, I'm not going to chase down a datasheet you should have provided a link for.  The annoying writing puts it over the top.  -1 and voting to close this mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "resistive input" is obviously an input with a relatively high impedance, such as a voltage divider.  The risk is that the ADC input may load this, and alter the intended voltage - and it may do so in a manner that is not constant over time, but rather pulse-like.

Many microcontroller ADC inputs have an effective input impedance which is actually a function of the software-configured sample and/or clock rate.  Other factors such as internal gain may also play a role.  Generally, the faster you sample, the lower impedance the input is going to present (ie, the more it will load the driving circuit).

Some recent microcontrollers have an op-amp buffer stage you can enable in front of the ADC.  If not, you can build your own op-amp voltage follower externally.